# Need help in Jolt transform for a very complex Input JSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming a very complex nested JSON using jolt transformation.  Input and output detail is given below.

```json
{
  "headers": {
    "SAP_MessageProcessingLogID": "AGN8Q1LAvaftfquPZgITeSFFaTOQ",
    "SAP_PregeneratedMplId": "AGN8Q1SyLAPV51wXjKeFzGT2geJ0",
    "X-dynaTrace": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004���F\u0000\u0000Lv\u0000\u0000\u0000\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001ci�����#�\u0000\u0000\u0002=?�\u0004\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0006\b���F\b\b\u0000\u0000Lv\f G[�����\b��y'��X�\u000e\u0010�q)d�;\u0001}",
    "breadcrumbId": "ID-8c1f6f36-fe53-4d97-704a-6e6d-1669077660632-34-16",
    "SAP_MplCorrelationId": "AGN8Q1K-eWeazc4vLsQJt_lwCV58"
  },
  "key": {
    "eventSource": "DM4003_MDG_D_BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest",
    "eventKey": "100016"
  },
  "value": {
    "metadata": {
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventSource": "DM4003_MDG_D_BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest",
      "eventName": "",
      "eventTime": "2022-06-10T15:43:10Z",
      "eventID": "027F9B28D8161EDCBA9A80F42F397632",
      "eventKey": "100016"
    },
    "payload": {
      "BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest": {
        "MessageHeader": {
          "ID": "027F9B28D8161EDCBA9A80F42F397632",
          "UUID": "027f9b28-d816-1edc-ba9a-80f42f397632",
          "CreationDateTime": "2022-06-10T15:43:10Z",
          "SenderBusinessSystemID": "DM4003_MDG_D",
          "RecipientBusinessSystemID": "RM5100_MDG_R"
        },
        "BusinessPartnerSUITEReplicateRequestMessage": [
          {
            "MessageHeader": {
              "ID": "027F9B28D8161EDCBA9A80F42F399632",
              "UUID": "027f9b28-d816-1edc-ba9a-80f42f399632",
              "CreationDateTime": "2022-06-10T15:43:10Z",
              "SenderBusinessSystemID": "DM4003_MDG_D",
              "RecipientBusinessSystemID": "RM5100_MDG_R"
            },
            "BusinessPartner": {
              "@actionCode": "04",
              "@changeOrdinalNumberValue": "1",
              "@reconciliationPeriodCounterValue": "1",
              "@multipleAssignmentListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@addressInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@addressIndependentInfoCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@bankDetailsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@paymentCardDetailsCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@commonListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@roleListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@identificationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@industrySectorListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@taxNumberListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@financialServicesCompanyCodeInformationCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@creditManagementCustomInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@creditManagementExternalCreditInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
              "@ZZSTOFORMCODE": "0000000000",
              "@ZZSTOBRANCODE": "0000000000",
              "@ZZCOMPSTAT": "0000000000",
              "@ZZCOMPSTATGRP": "0000000000",
              "UUID": "024f2eb6-b348-1edc-ba9a-393a4d5865e6",
              "InternalID": "100016",
              "CategoryCode": "2",
              "NumberRangeIntervalBusinessPartnerGroupCode": "ZRTS",
              "Customer": {
                "@accountingInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@salesArrangementListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@unloadingPointsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@taxClassificationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@customerTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@customerDocumentListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@propertyListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@propertyValuationCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "InternalID": "IN32",
                "MaintenanceProfileCode": "ZRTC",
                "AlternativePayeeAllowedIndicator": "false",
                "DeletionBlockedIndicator": "false",
                "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                "PostingBlockedIndicator": "false",
                "EqualizationTaxRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                "ValueAddedTaxRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                "ICMSExemptionIndicator": "false",
                "IPIExemptionIndicator": "false",
                "SaleSalesAndDistributionBlocks": {
                  "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false"
                },
                "MarketingAttributes": {
                  "AnnualSalesVolumeAmountReportedYear": "0000",
                  "EmployeeNumberValueReportedYear": "0000"
                },
                "CivilUseIndicator": "false",
                "MilitaryUseIndicator": "false",
                "LegalControlIndicators": {
                  "BiochemicalWarfareIndicator": "false",
                  "NuclearNonproliferationIndicator": "false",
                  "NationalSecurityIndicator": "false",
                  "MissileTechnologyIndicator": "false"
                },
                "AccountingInformation": {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "@dunningInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "@withholdingTaxListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "@accountingTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "CompanyID": "IN01",
                  "EmployeeID": "00000000",
                  "BlockedIndicator": "false",
                  "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                  "GeneralLedgerAccountReference": {
                    "ID": "1110211001"
                  },
                  "PaymentNoticeAccountingIndicator": "false",
                  "CustomerSupplierClearingIndicator": "false",
                  "InterestCalculationFrequencyCode": "00",
                  "InsuredAmount": {
                    "@currencyCode": "INR",
                    "$": "0.0"
                  },
                  "InsuranceLeadDuration": "P023M",
                  "LocalProcessingIndicator": "false",
                  "RecordPaymentHistoryIndicator": "false",
                  "ProbableCheckPaidDuration": "P023D",
                  "PayItemsSeparatelyIndicator": "false",
                  "PaymentAdvicesByEDIIndicator": "false",
                  "DeletionBlockedIndicator": "false"
                },
                "SalesArrangement": [
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "10",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "CurrencyCode": "INR",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "20",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "30",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "40",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "50",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "60",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "@partnerFunctionsListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@salesArrangementTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "SalesOrganisationID": "IN01",
                    "DistributionChannelCode": "70",
                    "DivisionCode": "10",
                    "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingProcedureDeterminationCodeLong": "01",
                    "SalesDistrictCode": "000001",
                    "PriceGroupCode": "01",
                    "BatchSplitAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "ManualInvoiceMaintenanceIndicator": "false",
                    "RebateRelevantIndicator": "false",
                    "PricingRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "SalesSupportBlockedIndicator": "false",
                    "RoundingSwitchOffIndicator": "false",
                    "AgencyBusinessRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                    "PODConfirmationTimeframeDuration": "P023D",
                    "DocumentIndexAllowedIndicator": "false",
                    "DeliveryTerms": {
                      "DeliveryPriorityCode": "00",
                      "SalesOrderCompleteDeliveryIndicator": "false",
                      "OrderCombinationAllowedIndicator": "false",
                      "QuantityTolerance": {
                        "OverPercentUnlimitedIndicator": "false"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "TaxClassification": {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "TaxCountryCode": "IN",
                  "TaxTypeCode": "JTX4"
                }
              },
              "Supplier": {
                "@accountingInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@procurementCardIssuingInstitutesListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "false",
                "@qualitiyManagementListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "false",
                "@procurementArrangementListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@subRangeListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@supplierTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@supplierDocumentListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@propertyListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "@propertyValuationCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                "InternalID": "IN32",
                "MaintenanceProfileCode": "ZRTV",
                "DeletionBlockedIndicator": "false",
                "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                "PostingBlockedIndicator": "false",
                "PurchasingBlockedIndicator": "false",
                "AlternativePayeeAllowedIndicator": "false",
                "EqualizationTaxRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                "ValueAddedTaxRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                "SellerAssortmentProductGroupLevelRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                "PlantLevelRelevanceIndicator": "false",
                "ForSocialInsuranceRegisteredIndicator": "false",
                "TaxSplitIndicator": "false",
                "TaxBasePercentageCode": "0",
                "CollectiveNumberingRelevancyIndicator": "false",
                "StagingDuration": "P023D",
                "AccountingInformation": {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "@dunningInformationListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "@withholdingTaxListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "@accountingTextListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "CompanyID": "IN01",
                  "BlockedIndicator": "false",
                  "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                  "GeneralLedgerAccountReference": {
                    "ID": "2110201001"
                  },
                  "InterestCalculationFrequencyCode": "00",
                  "LocalProcessingIndicator": "false",
                  "ProbableCheckPaidDuration": "P023D",
                  "DoubleEntriesCheckIndicator": "false",
                  "PayItemsSeparatelyIndicator": "false",
                  "EmployeeID": "00000000",
                  "PaymentAdvicesByEDIIndicator": "false",
                  "DeletionBlockedIndicator": "false",
                  "CustomerSupplierClearingIndicator": "false"
                }
              },
              "AddressInformation": [
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "@addressUsageListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                  "UUID": "024f2eb6-b348-1edc-ba9a-393a4d5ac5e6",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  },
                  "AddressUsage": {
                    "@actionCode": "04",
                    "AddressUsageCode": "XXDEFAULT",
                    "ValidityPeriod": {
                      "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                      "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                    },
                    "DefaultIndicator": "false"
                  },
                  "Address": {
                    "@addressNoteListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@emailListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@facsimileListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@organisationNameListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@personNameListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@postalAddressListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@telephoneListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "@webListCompleteTransmissionIndicator": "true",
                    "CommunicationPreference": {
                      "@actionCode": "04",
                      "CorrespondenceLanguageCode": "EN"
                    },
                    "PostalAddress": [
                      {
                        "@actionCode": "04",
                        "CountryCode": "IN",
                        "CityName": "Bengaluru",
                        "StreetPostalCode": "560066",
                        "StreetName": "No.62 Prestige Ozone",
                        "POBoxIDVisibleIndicator": "false",
                        "TimeZoneCode": "INDIA"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "Common": [
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "LocationStandardID": {
                    "@schemeAgencyID": "1",
                    "$": "0000000000000"
                  },
                  "DeletedIndicator": "false",
                  "ReleasedIndicator": "true",
                  "BlockedIndicator": "false",
                  "KeyWordsText": "ADIDAS INDIA MARKETI",
                  "CorrespondenceBrailleRequiredIndicator": "false",
                  "CorrespondenceLargePrintRequiredIndicator": "false",
                  "NaturalPersonIndicator": "false",
                  "Organisation": {
                    "Name": {
                      "FirstLineName": "adidas India Marketing Pvt.Ltd"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "Role": [
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "RoleCode": "BPSITE",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "RoleCode": "FLCU00",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "RoleCode": "FLCU01",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "RoleCode": "FLVN00",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "RoleCode": "FLVN01",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "Identification": [
                {
                  "@actionCode": "04",
                  "PartyIdentifierTypeCode": "ZPLANT",
                  "BusinessPartnerID": "KA01",
                  "EntryDate": "2022-06-10",
                  "ValidityPeriod": {
                    "StartDate": "2022-06-10",
                    "EndDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "CreditManagementCreditWorthiness": {
                "AffidavitForAssetsMadeIndicator": "false",
                "BankruptcyProceedingsInitiatedIndicator": "false",
                "ForeclosureProceedingsInitiatedIndicator": "false"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ouput I need the below columns in a flattened way, the distributionchannelcode is coming in a array, i wanted to flatten it. I m not able to achieve it

```json
{
  "Location" : "027F9B28D8161EDCBA9A80F42F399632",
  "DistributionChannelCode" : [ "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70" ],
  "SAP Company code" : "IN01",
  "LocationCountry" : "IN",
  "InternationalLocationName" : "xyz"
}
```

Jolt Spec i tried

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "payload": {
          "BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest": {
            "BusinessPartnerSUITEReplicateRequestMessage": {
              "*": {
                "MessageHeader": {
                  "ID": "Location"
                },
                "BusinessPartner": {
                  "Customer": {
                    "SalesArrangement": {
                      "*": {
                        "DistributionChannelCode": "DistributionChannelCode"
                      }
                    },
                    "AccountingInformation": {
                      "CompanyID": "SAP Company code"
                    }
                  },
                  "AddressInformation": {
                    "*": {
                      "Address": {
                        "PostalAddress": {
                          "*": {
                            "CountryCode": "LocationCountry"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "Common": {
                    "*": {
                      "Organisation": {
                        "Name": {
                          "FirstLineName": "InternationalLocationName"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Can anyone who is a jolt expert, help me get the desired output. I think i m stuck in the last step

Comment: Do you want to dissipate the seven components to seven different objects while the other attributes repeating within each ?

Comment: Yes Barbaros. other attributes should be repeating within each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this **`shift`** transformation spec to the current one

```json
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "DistributionChannelCode": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,Location)": "[#2].Location",
          "@": "[#2].&2", // replicates the "DistributionChannelCode" tag going tree two levels up
          "@(2,SAP Company code)": "[#2].SAP Company code",
          "@(2,LocationCountry)": "[#2].LocationCountry",
          "@(2,InternationalLocationName)": "[#2].InternationalLocationName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

in order to dissipate each attributes to seven different objects, as **`DistributionChannelCode`** having seven components.